# Change Input size in column

Tags: html, css

I have a table, with input fields in the 1st column. Now I just want to change the size of the **email input field.** But If I change it, all input field automatically take the size too. What do I have to change here?

```
<table >
      <tbody class="thsize">

            <tr class="thsize">
                <th class="thsize">First Name</th>
                <td class="thsize">
                    <input class="form-control" id="firstName" ngControl="firstName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="webUser.firstName"  #firstName="ngForm">
                </td>
                <td class="thsize"></td>        

                <th class="thsize">Last Name</th>
                <td class="thsize">
                    <input class="form-control" id="lastName" ngControl="lastName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="webUser.lastName"  #lastName="ngForm">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="thsize">
            <th class="thsize">Email</th>
                <td class="thsize">
                    <input style="width:300px;" class="form-control"  id="email" ngControl="email" type="text" [(ngModel)]="webUser.email"  #email="ngForm">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="thsize">
                <th class="thsize">Country</th>
                <td class="thsize">
                    <input class="form-control" id="country" ngControl="country" type="text" [(ngModel)]="webUser.country"  #country="ngForm">
                </td>
                <td class="thsize"></td>        

                <th class="thsize">Language</th>
                <td class="thsize">
                    {{webUser.language}}
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

if I put `style="width:300px;"` in the email Input field, then alle other fields in this columns automatically gets the width = 300.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to me the reason that all the other fields change to width 300 is because you use `class = "form-control"`. So by calling the same class, and changing the style inline, you might be overriding any width you've given in the place where form-control is defined.

Never mind. @Lalji has a better solution.

Comment: I don't understand the table at all. The rows have different number of columns. And why are there table headers defined in each row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table >
      <tbody class="thsize">

            <tr class="thsize">
                <th class="thsize">First Name</th>
                <td class="thsize">
                    <input class="form-control" id="firstName" ngControl="firstName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="webUser.firstName"  #firstName="ngForm">
                </td>
                <td class="thsize"></td>        

                <th class="thsize">Last Name</th>
                <td class="thsize">
                    <input class="form-control" id="lastName" ngControl="lastName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="webUser.lastName"  #lastName="ngForm">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="thsize">
            <th class="thsize">Email</th>
                <td class="thsize" colspan="4">
                    <input class="form-control"  id="email" ngControl="email" type="text" [(ngModel)]="webUser.email"  #email="ngForm">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="thsize">
                <th class="thsize">Country</th>
                <td class="thsize">
                    <input class="form-control" id="country" ngControl="country" type="text" [(ngModel)]="webUser.country"  #country="ngForm">
                </td>
                <td class="thsize"></td>        

                <th class="thsize">Language</th>
                <td class="thsize">
                    {{webUser.language}}
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

add colspan

```
<td class="thsize" colspan="4">
                    <input style="width:300px;" class="form-control"  id="email" ngControl="email" type="text" [(ngModel)]="webUser.email"  #email="ngForm">
                </td>
```

Comment: if you want full with then remove width inline

Comment: @trap as lalji said, remove style="width:300px;" and use col-span as mentioned! :)

Comment: Now it worked. Thank you very much4 all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 table{width:300px; table-layout:fixed;}
table tr td,table tr th{width:20%;word-wrap: break-word;}
table tr td.thsize > input{width:100%;}
```

```css
table{width:300px; table-layout:fixed;}
table tr td,table tr th{width:20%;word-wrap: break-word;}
table tr td.thsize > input{width:100%;}
```

```html
<table >
      <tbody class="thsize">

            <tr class="thsize">
                <th class="thsize">First Name</th>
                <td class="thsize">
                    <input class="form-control" id="firstName" ngControl="firstName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="webUser.firstName"  #firstName="ngForm">
                </td>
                <td class="thsize"></td>        

                <th class="thsize">Last Name</th>
                <td class="thsize">
                    <input class="form-control" id="lastName" ngControl="lastName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="webUser.lastName"  #lastName="ngForm">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="thsize">
            <th class="thsize">Email</th>
                <td class="thsize">
                    <input  class="form-control"  id="email" ngControl="email" type="text" [(ngModel)]="webUser.email"  #email="ngForm">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="thsize">
                <th class="thsize">Country</th>
                <td class="thsize">
                    <input class="form-control" id="country" ngControl="country" type="text" [(ngModel)]="webUser.country"  #country="ngForm">
                </td>
                <td class="thsize"></td>        

                <th class="thsize">Language</th>
                <td class="thsize">
                    {{webUser.language}}
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: if you are using bootstrap use .table class with<table class="table">